# morphia save() method - how to determine success or failure

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia 0.109 with MongoDB.  My document collection uses String values for the _id field, e.g.

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private String entityId;
  ...
}
```

When I call the Datastore or BasicDAO save() method to insert one of these items, I fill in the _id field (entityId) with a unique value as is required.  The save() method returns a value of type Key.

My question is, how can I determine, from examining the returned Key, whether the save operation succeeded or failed?  I cannot rely on the trick of checking to see if Morphia filled in the _id field, since I had to fill it in prior to calling save().

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're using a `String` instead of an `ObjectId`. Is there a particular reason for that?

In general, use the right [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) for your situation, which is a trade-off between speed and data safety. You'll run into an exception if your stated requirements cannot be fulfilled — for example for `JOURNAL_SAFE`

> **Exceptions are raised for network issues, and server errors**; the write operation waits for the server to group commit to the journal file on disk.

Comment: I am not using ObjectId because I don't need MongoDB to add a gratuitous item to my documents.  I already have a unique string-valued key.

Comment: I don't see how WriteConcern addresses my issue.  My problem is not about how long MongoDB waits before confirming that the write succeeded, it is about how MongoDB communicates the success or failure to me.

Comment: MongoDB is generally optimized towards the good / regular case, for example using optimistic locking instead of pessimistic locking. So if something goes wrong, it throws an exception (example added to the initial answer); if everything works fine, nothing / no exception happens. Using ``String`` for the ``_id`` can work well, just watch out if you run into issues when using ``@Reference`` with it.

Comment: The Morphia API's do not include "throws" clauses, so how do I know what exceptions will be thrown and under what circumstances?

Comment: It's an unchecked exception, so take a look at the source code: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/c173ed02bd4d8f625f4fcf0d01fe7c8eb2e41c74/src/main/com/mongodb/DBCollection.java#L997-L1015 Note that ``save()`` returns ``WriteResult`` and you could use its method ``getError()``, but this is deprecated since the information is already in the exception